# Magento 2 Developer Toolbars

Tags: magento2, debugging, toolbar

When developing themes and modules for Magento 2 I came across a barrier, how can I debug better?
So I come here to ask, what are the best developer toolbars for Magento 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tested the best developer toolbars, I'll put down the more I liked it.

1. [ADM/QuickDevBar](https://github.com/vpietri/magento2-developer-quickdevbar)

**Info** : Information about controller, route, action and store. A dedicated tab output a phpinfo.

**Design** : List handles called and display layout structure of nested blocks and containers

**Profile** : View current observers, all events dispatched and collections, models loaded

**Queries** : Statistics about executed queries and detailed query listing 
with syntax highlighting of main SQL keywords

**Logs** : Display log files with ability to reset these files

**Actions** : Easily toggle template hints and inline translation and flush cache

2. [Mirasvit/Module-profiler](https://github.com/mirasvit/module-profiler)
3. [Balloz/Magento2-developer-toolbar](https://github.com/balloz/magento2-developer-toolbar)

Answer (score 1):

The best developer toolbar I came accross is the one developed by **[Alan Storm called Commerce Bug](http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/commerce-bug-3)** ($99.95)

It handles:

- Details of the request
- List of CRUD Models calls
- List of collections calls
- List of blocks
- Details of the layout
- List of other classes calls
- List of events dispatched
- List of observers called
- An alias lookup tool
- System tasks actions such as cache clearing, template hints toggling, Magento logging toggling, inline translation toggling.